# Moving the statistics question was the wrong choice

Tags: discussion, moderation

There are several reasons I disagree with the decision to move this [statistics question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8347/is-bayesian-statistics-genuinely-an-improvement-over-traditional-frequentist-st).

1.) The question was framed towards skepticism, not statistics.  An answer has been given already on the other board and it is completely inappropriate to what I asked.

2.) It was my question, addressed to this community.  Having no control over the question that I ask is extremely disempowering.

3.) My login here does not carry over to the statistics board. Please don't make the users chase their questions AND re-register at each place you move their questions to.

4.) Most importantly, there were better options.  It would have been more appropriate to simply close the question.  If I WANTED to go ask on the stats board, I could then have    done so.

I understand not everyone agrees it was an appropriate question.  That's fine and that's how the site works.  If it is voted to be closed, so be it.  Moving it, though, was inappropriate.  I would like to suggest that this action be only taken at the request or permission of the questionner in the future.

Answer (score 3):

> 1.) The question was framed towards skepticism, not statistics. An answer
>   has been given already on the other
>   board and it is completely
>   inappropriate to what I asked.

On Cross Validated you got 2 answers more in a relatively short time, while you only got one very short one in the time this question was open here. You weren't getting good answers here, so I don't think this is an argument against migration.

> 2.) It was my question, addressed to this community. Having no control over
>   the question that I ask is extremely
>   disempowering.

All questions and answers are licensed under a Creative Commons license, this means they can be used on other sites as long as proper attribution is given. It takes a while getting used to it, especially when you see your posts the first time on sites that just take the content of the whole StackExchange network and publish it somewhere else. Your question does not only belong to you after you post it here, anyone can use it under the terms of the license. I consider this one of the big strengths of the StackExchange sites, as the content here can not be hidden behind a paywall, it will always remain free under the CC license.

Your question can also be edited by high-reputation users, also taking control away from you. Those are features that, in my opinion, make SE sites better, but it can certainly be unexpected.

The main objective of any of the Q&A sites here is to get good answers to questions. Migration of questions is one way to achieve this, and it is usually much less frustrating to the asker than just closing the question.

> 3.) My login here does not carry over to the statistics board. Please don't
>   make the users chase their questions
>   AND re-register at each place you move
>   their questions to.

It takes me about 2 clicks to create an account on a different SE site, it is somewhat annoying, but you also don't absolutely need this second account. You can still see the answers to your question, you only need the account if you want to interact further with the answerers.

> 4.) Most importantly, there were better options. It would have been
>   more appropriate to simply close the
>   question. If I WANTED to go ask on the
>   stats board, I could then have done
>   so.

Wanting the question closed instead of migrated is a very unusual request. Migrating questions is meant to make it easier for people who accidentally post on the wrong site. Just closing the question seems somewhat hostile, migrating might ensure that they get their answer and it seems a lot friendlier.

I acknowledge that this is not exactly a typical case, but we can't really ask everyone before migrating questions. It will only confuse most people, and I think the cases were migration is not wanted are by far the minority. The current procedure is appropriate for most cases, but there will always be exceptions.

If you still want to close your question on Cross Validated, I can relay that to a mod on that site.

Comment: 1.) They were answers but they didn't answer the question.  It could have been moved to a site about ponies and gotten responses there too.

Comment: @MindDetective I don't know enough about the subject to judge the answers, but my point is that you also did not get good answers here.

Comment: 2.) I'm know I don't own the content, but it was me asking.  Presumably it was being moved on my behalf.  If someone else was interested in an answer, then it might make sense.  Instead, I get the impression it is more like a "get off my lawn!" decision.  3.) Great, but it is not really very user friendly, especially if it is for my own benefit.  4.) I think it was appropriate for this site.  Are statisticians encouraged to stay in their own camp?

Comment: @Fabian And that is bound to happen with many questions.  Passing the buck just doesn't seem like good policy for this particular site.

Comment: I can honestly say that I was interested in the answer, and up voted the question as soon as I saw it.  But I have very little interest in the stats community as a whole, and I'm not looking to join it and clutter up my notifications and whoseiwhats.  That being said, i think MD is saying he knows you CAN do it, but SHOULD you?  Seems rude to move someone's question without at least asking.  Poor form more than a violation of rules.

Comment: @Dogmafrog we did [discuss the decision](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/200/are-applied-mathematics-questions-on-topic) to migrate it. Moreover, the poster doesn't ultimately decide what stays here and what doesn't; the community does.

Comment: I don't know that SE mods "shoot from the hip" (at least, not *all* the time). ;-) Disempowering? How about that plus *discouraging* for mods who try to keep the place chugging along but that they could be overruled at any time... what's the point of that?

Comment: Any migration, up vote, down vote, accepted answer, etc.... should be able to be challenged in some way (even if only through comments). You challenged it here, and a decent case was given for the action taken. Had the community not received better answers in a shorter amount of time, then maybe there would have been a good case to move it back. Furthermore, anyone who finds it here will (should) also see the "migrated to" link and still find it if they're indeed interested.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that moving a question should only be done with the permission of the questioner.  There are some groups on SO that I don't want to be a part of, and so I might not want to go where you're moving my question.  Mind detective is correct, if he wanted it on the other board he could have moved it himself.

I also disagree that is was inappropriate for this site, there is a pretty big controversy in statistics about that issue, and it would have been good to challenge the preconceptions and "dogma" here.  I'm not even a stats guy, and I've heard about it.

Comment: You don't need to be a part of anything to read the question page on the other site, and whether or not the post is off-topic is not in question here.